# FindFirst returns null

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm to provide the database for my application. But...

After login, the server returns the data and I create the account (of AccountManager) and save these datas at the database of the application, like this (at an AsyncTask, of course):

```
UserRealm userRealm = new UserRealm();
//setter of the userRealm...

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userRealm);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

After, I close the LoginActivity and at the onResume of the MainActivity, I try to load the user, like this(at an AsyncTask, again...):

```
public static UserRealm getUser(Context context) {
  try {
    return Realm.getInstance(context).where(UserRealm.class).findFirst();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    if(DebugUtil.DEBUG) { //enabled
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

But this returns null, I don't know what happens with it.

UserRealm: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/88f2553a6ff990876bc6

Comment: Can you post your stacktarce...

Comment: No one error or warning at stacktrace...

Comment: Can you please check the query result immediately after write transaction in the first code block? And share the `UserRealmRealmProxy.java` which is generated by Realm in the build folder if you can.

Comment: I tested to call getUser() after this transaction and works fine, this returns the UserRealm object...

Comment: I've implemented an workaround to sent the User instance (an wrapper of UserRealm that's not extends RealmObject, but have the similar structure) via EventBus to the MainActivity to show the user. But this can be a problem at the restart of the app ...

Comment: No one? It's bizarre...

Comment: can you post your UserRealm class code as well, please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is in a threadpool, and considering you open Realm instances that you never close with your `getUser()` call, your Realm version becomes locked at the version when you first called `getUser()`.

> **`return Realm.getInstance(context)`**.where(UserRealm.class).findFirst(); *// never closed*

So even though you commit a transaction on another thread in the threadpool, not all threads will be up to date (because you locked them on an old version by opening Realm instances that are never closed), and sometimes the object will be null.

Solution, close all Realm instances on background threads (or [force an update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839808/2413303) if that's not enough for some reason).